# Kivy, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' when building an android app

Tags: python, android, kivy, importerror

I'm trying to build my first android app. I installed Kivy, buildozer and coded "hello world" as [here](https://www.digitaljunky.io/make-a-snake-game-for-android-written-in-python-part-1/). Then, I input "buildozer android debug" and it threw an error, "bla bla bla sdk directory is not specified" in this command:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=test2 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/whiteblackgoose/PycharmProjects/mobileapp/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21
```

So I added some arguments to the command and made it work:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=test2 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/whiteblackgoose/PycharmProjects/mobileapp/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21 --sdk-dir=/home/whiteblackgoose/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk --ndk-dir=/home/whiteblackgoose/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
```

So when I'm trying to run it, it threw a new error:

```
File "/home/whiteblackgoose/PycharmProjects/mobileapp/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'


  STDERR:
```

I reinstalled cython and tried to import ctypes and _ctypes:

```
whiteblackgoose@whiteblackgoose-VirtualBox:~/PycharmProjects/mobileapp/test2$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> import _ctypes
>>>
```

As you can see, when I import them there's no problem. But if I run the command above, it says, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'".

How do I make visible this module for buildozer? Or mb the problem is caused by an installed package or incorrect version of something...

Comment: I think you have a broken build for some reason, could you clean it (delete the .buildozer dir in your application directory) and run buildozer again, posting the full log output if it crashes again?

Comment: Also the error relates to the _ctypes import within an internal python build, it doesn't matter that you have a working ctypes in the system python.

Comment: I tried to remove the dir and run buildozer again. What changed is that now I dont run this command manually but I run "buildozer android debug" and the error occures.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install the libffi headers. These come from the `libffi-dev` package on Ubuntu, and usually something similar in other distros.

After that, clean the build by deleting the `.buildozer` directory in your app dir and building again.

Comment: Exactly. Installing the libffi-dev package using `sudo apt install libffi-dev` and deleting the `.buildozer` directory solved my issue.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem and already (i Think) done everything

* added libffi as the first rquirement in the buildozer file
* installed libffi-dev
* cleared buildozer
* main.py is the main

Still got the ctype error

Comment: @CarstenThielepape Did you clean the buildozer build before retrying? i.e. delete the .buildozer dir in your build directory

Comment: @jjmerelo On the contrary there is a direct causal relationship between this and the error reported, and I've talked to lots of different people who resolved their issues this way.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue with Ubuntu 20.04.
As suggested above, I did installed the `libffi-dev` packag, but it didn't help.

I deleted the ~/.local/ directory and re-tried building apk; it worked for me.