# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' with buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, ctypes, buildozer

I am trying for the first time to build an android app with kivy and buildozer, on linux mint. But, when I run:

> buildozer -v android debug

It throws an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

Following instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57655121/kivy-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-building-an-android-ap) I installed libffi-dev and deleted the .buildozer directory. However, rerunning:

> buildozer -v android debug
> Still throws the following error.

```
File "/home/yimeca/Documents/Python/kivy/clock_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

(After I deleted the .buildozer directory, it didn't recreate - I'm not sure if it should have. I had backed it up, and have now replaced it. This has made no difference.)

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3: ImportError: No module named '\_ctypes' when using Value from module multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul)